# Alternative way of zen_image_submit() to submit form in ZenCart

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, zen-cart

I want to use

```
<input type="submit" .....>
```

instead of

```
type="image"
```

So, is there any way to do this thing in ZenCart?
Currently, I'm using

```
zen_image_submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Duplicate the template file, comment out the `zen_image_submit()` line and add your own `<input>` or `<submit>` html.

---

Having looked at the [ZenCart function list](http://www.sourcexref.com/xref/zencart/nav.html?_functions/index.html), I didn't see an alternative to `zen_image_submit()`.

I did not check to see if there was a plugin because my fix simply involved overriding the template, inside of my theme, with a hard-coded HTML button:

```
<button type="submit" class="pure-button"><?=BUTTON_CREATE_TEXT?></button>
<!--<?php echo zen_image_submit(BUTTON_IMAGE_SUBMIT, BUTTON_SUBMIT_ALT); ?>-->
```

In the above example, I also create a new constant in my theme's english.php file (`includes/languages/my_theme/english.php`):

```
define('BUTTON_CREATE_TEXT', 'Create');
```

Doing the above requires one to make copies of (core) files and put them in their theme, but if you're already doing this to override other features, then it's not such a biggy.

**Note:** In order to make sure my custom HTML `<button>`/`<submit>` markup <s>is correct</s> **has all of the required attributes**, I'll view the source of the page before making changes and view/copy the output of `zen_image_submit()`; doing this allows me to copy/retain attributes like `name="..."`.

Comment: ummm,,, You are right, I think; this is the only way..
By the way, thank you for looking at the question.

Comment: Yah, I had the exact same question. After not seeing an alternative function in the API, I figured the manual approach of adding HTML wasn't a bad solution ... I did not investigate plugins; using a plugin could be better in that it would apply the changes globally without having to duplicate template files. Anyway, thanks for the comment!